# I want to create a USA map with city locator

Tags: r, maps

I am trying to make a map of USA cities for my essay.

I have data with lat and long values for 417 cities in the USA. 1) I was able to load the data in R. 2) I was able to get the state map too. However, I am not able to get the city points on the map. I have used code mentioned in one of the posts from the platform.

```r
setwd("C:/Users/sanke/Dropbox/My PC (DESKTOP-HI769JF)/Downloads/map")
install.packages("maps")
install.packages("readxl")
library(maps)
library(readxl)
dat <- read_excel("map.xlsx")
US <- dat[dat$country_txt == "United States",]

map('state') # This give the state map

points(x=US$latitude, y=US$longitude, col="red", cex=0.75)
# I don't get output after this code
```

Comment: Try reversing lat and long, as in `points(x=US$longitude, y=US$latitude, col="red", cex=0.75)`.

Comment: BTW, it helps with sample code to use syntactically correct code; it makes more sense to use `#` instead of `//` here.

Comment: Please consider going back to your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8189341/sanket-kanekar?tab=questions) and accepting answers by clicking on the check-mark; this indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.